# MapReduce read text files and write results in an excel file

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to write a MapReduce program in which i can write my output to an excel file. Can this be done using hadoop API writer classes or i have to use some other API for this. I don't have a vast knowledge of hadoop so i need your help in doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an actual need to read/write Excel files, I recommend you look at [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/). That being said, CSV files are much easier. You can try using [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/), if that helps; although it's easy enough to work with CSV files that you can use Hadoop by itself for that.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to output to a comma-separated values (CSV) file, which can be opened in Excel: [CSV File](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)

Comment: Thanks i will start.. :)